# Replace text in third-party iframe with separate JS file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have a site that uses content from a third-party displayed in an iframe. The third-party allows the upload of CSS or JS files in the head of their site, so I am able to change the look of the content inside the iframe. It is not possible to change the location of where the file is loaded on their end (such as moving all JS files after the body).

Here's the issue: I'm trying to change the text of a div and am unable to do it through my JS file.

```
<div id="exampleText">
    There's nothing here!
    <span>Try again at 4:00</span>
</div>
```

I know that I can use `.html` or `.innerHTML` or even `nodeType === 3` and set `nodeValue` to replace the content. Here's one of the ways that works when placed inside the browser console of the page:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    document.getElementById('exampleText').innerHTML =
    "Sorry, you're too early!<span>Check back one hour before class starts</span>";
});
```

However, when I place this inside my JS file and refresh the page, I get an error that states:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null(…)
```

Why does it work when placed inside the page through the browser console, but not from within the file? Is it due to the site loading after the JS is run? How can I fix this to replace the text with my own content?

Comment: What is the URL of your page? What is the URL of the IFRAME? You only can modify the IFRAME if they are in the same domain.

Comment: You are probably going to suffer the same origin policy. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy which says: `The same-origin policy restricts how a document or script loaded from one origin can interact with a resource from another origin. It is a critical security mechanism for isolating potentially malicious documents.`. This is a by-design policy by which browser developers specifically protect cross-frame DOM changes when the sources of the frames differ. Reason why it works in console is because that is not scripted - you have to manually do it.

Comment: I've used the same JS file to replace content on other iframes from the same site previously, so I'm unsure why this one page would be the only one affected by CORS. The file is not hosted on my site and is run on their end from within the iframe. It seems to me that the content isn't loaded before the JS runs resulting in a null error, but I'm not sure how to check for this or run it at a later point from within the head.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not find a way to do this easily through JS, but I was able to replace the content with CSS instead. Here is how I managed it:

```
#exampleText {
    text-indent: -9999px;
    line-height: 0;
}

#exampleText span,
#exampleText span:before {
    text-indent: 0;
    line-height: initial;
}

#exampleText span:before {
    content: "Sorry, you're too early!";
    display: block;
    font-weight: 700;
}
```

This method allows me to keep the span text the same while updating only the content with no surrounding element.